# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (AVAsset merging video and audio into one video)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift4

I am facing this really weird problem. I am trying to merge a video track and an audio track when touching a button. The first time I touch the button, it starts to record both the video and the audio (for some reason I need them separately), and for the second time, it stops the recording and creates two URL that points to the video and the audio.

Here comes the weird thing. When I put the function together like this:

```
@objc func touchCameraButton(){

    if isVideoRecordingOn{

        if isFirstTouch{
            startCapture()
            recordAudio()
            isFirstTouch = false
        }else{
            startCapture()
            recordAudio()
            self.mergeVideoAndAudio(videoUrl: videoFileURL, audioUrl: soundFileURL!, shouldFlipHorizontally: true, completion: {(err, url) in
                self.videoWithAudioURL = url
                if (err != nil){
                    print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Error in merging video and audio")
                }
                self.isFirstTouch = true
                })
    }
    }
}
```

It does not work and raises the uncaught exception of type NSException.

However, if I put the merge function separately in another button, the whole program works fine. It looks like this:

```
@objc func touchCameraButton(){

    if isVideoRecordingOn{

        if isFirstTouch{
            startCapture()
            recordAudio()
            isFirstTouch = false
        }else{
            startCapture()
            recordAudio()
//                startCapture()
//                recordAudio()
//                self.mergeVideoAndAudio(videoUrl: videoFileURL, audioUrl: soundFileURL!, shouldFlipHorizontally: true, completion: {(err, url) in
//                    self.videoWithAudioURL = url
//                    if (err != nil){
//                        print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Error in merging video and audio")
//                    }
//                    self.isFirstTouch = true
//                    })
    }
    }
}


@IBAction func touchSomeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.mergeVideoAndAudio(videoUrl: videoFileURL, audioUrl: soundFileURL!, shouldFlipHorizontally: true, completion: {(err, url) in
        self.videoWithAudioURL = url
        if (err != nil){
            print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Error in merging video and audio")
        }
    })
}
```

I've been stuck into this problem for two days and have absolutely no idea about what's going on. I guess it might be some problem with the background thread and main thread that I do not know.

Comment: Show full error message. You should have at some point "Terminating" (starting with an uppercase) and "NSUncaughtException" (and not NSException) in console at the beginning of the useful error message until the line you gave.

Comment: @Larme What do you mean by that? I'm relatively new to XCode...